# How to render a .vox voxel model in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, voxel

I need help with rendering a .vox model in OpenGL.

[The .VOX file format is described here](https://ephtracy.github.io/index.html?page=mv_vox_format).

[Here is an example VOX file reader.](https://voxel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MV%20Importer/MV%20Importer/mv_vox.h)

And here is where I come across the problem - how would I go about rendering a .vox model in OpenGL? I know how to render standard .obj models with textures using the Phong reflection model, but how do I handle voxel data? What kind of data should I pass to the shaders? Should I parse the data somehow, to get the index of each individual voxel to parse? How should I create vertices based on voxel data (should I even do that)? Should I pass all the chunks or is there a simple way to filter out those that won't be visible?

I tried searching for information on this topic, but came up empty. What I am trying to accomplish is something like MagicaVoxel Viewer, but much simpler, without all those customizable options and with only a single light source.

I'm not trying to look for a ready solution, but if anyone could even point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: How do you want to render a voxel image?

Comment: google  Volume rendering

Comment: It seems, the format just supports solid cubes (which they call voxels). So the easiest way is to create a cube for each voxel and render those.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I decided to render the cubes in two ways:

1) Based on voxel data, I will generate vertices and feed them to the pipeline.
2) Using the geometric shader, I'll emit vertices based on indexes of voxels to render I feed to the pipeline. I'll store the entire model as a 3D texture.